# Should we have a [free-pascal] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

For a [pascal](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pascal), [delphi](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delphi), [pascal-script](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pascal-script) related question: [Pascal / Delphi / Pascal Script tags](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1944/pascal-delphi-pascal-script-tags)

For a discussion about how the pascal related tags should be organized (as synonymous, for example), please see [(pascal) vs (free-pascal) vs (delphi) vs (delphi-xe) vs (object-pascal)](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6137/pascal-vs-free-pascal-vs-delphi-vs-delphi-xe-vs-object-pascal)

---

What about a [free-pascal](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/free-pascal) tag?

Object Free Pascal (as in Free Pascal compiler), as far as I know, is given by the directive:

```
{$mode objfpc}{$H+}
```

The compiler supports Delphi as well, but not completely:

```
{$mode DELPHI}
```

For other Free Pascal modes, please see [the documentation](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/user/userse33.html).

Comment: How many questions is there that would benefit from this tag?

Comment: I don't know. I don't even know how to count them, if any. Is there some chance that only me have made a  Free Pascal related question? http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/75653/sync-eye-movements-with-external-events

Comment: I have posted a question here as well: http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,27821.0.html

Comment: [Searching for Free Pascal](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=free+pascal) lead me to one other question: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/38621/2041.

Comment: I think that the less the number of questions, the better can be the moderation. Imagine if you already had a lot of questions... What a waste, hum? Better starts now.

Comment: Could someone mind explaining the difference between "free Pascal" and the other existing tags?

Comment: Please, make me know if I need to update the question.

Comment: ~$ fpc -h Free Pascal Compiler version 2.6.4 [2014/04/20] for x86_64
Copyright (c) 1993-2014 by Florian Klaempfl and others
As you can see, It is Free Pascal.

Comment: Some differences here http://www.freepascal.org/port.var

Comment: Good reading http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_%28programming_language%29, at some extent, if you are thinking about parsimonious, Delphi tag should not exist. It is know as Pascal as well, but it uses a proprietary compiler.

Comment: a minor difference that came into my mind is that in free pascal objfpc directive you must to explicitly use the @ symbol to point a method to an event (ex: OnSomeEvent := @MyMethod;). For delphi it is not needed. A major difference is the compiler it self, i think... People how use Free Pascal tends to use Lazarus IDE as well. People how use Delphi tends to use the most recent (or some proprietary) Embarcadero IDE, or Turbo Delphi, or Delphi 7.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762611/why-would-a-delphi-programmer-use-lazarus-as-the-ide-instead-of-using-delphis-i some people talking about differences between delphi and lazarus

Comment: Possible duplicate of [(pascal) vs (free-pascal) vs (delphi) vs (delphi-xe) vs (object-pascal)](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/6137/pascal-vs-free-pascal-vs-delphi-vs-delphi-xe-vs-object-pascal)

Comment: Not a duplicate, this question was addressed to the creation of a specific tag, not a general discussion about how pascal tags should be organized.

Answer (score 1):

Now the [free-pascal](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/free-pascal) tag exists. To avoid fragmentation, it redirects to [pascal](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pascal). You can follow the discussion here: [(pascal) vs. (free-pascal)](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6129/pascal-vs-free-pascal).

Some remarks:

- Free Pascal Compiler (by Florian Klaempfl and others) is **also** a Pascal compiler. There are [several](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_compilers#Pascal_compilers) Pascal compilers with significant differences from one to another. Just to give you an example, Turbo Pascal is fully compatible with Free Pascal, but the opposite is not true.
- As the previous fact approaches its limit, working code for a compiler implies it will be broken code to another. As you should know, CodeReview is not a place for broken code.
- `Free Pascal`, `free` as in `freedom`, refers to the open source culture, and the licence allows both copyleft and copyright derivatives. Proprietary, closed source compilers do not. It has, as you can expect, huge impact on accessibility and hackability of the code.