# (pascal) vs. (free-pascal)

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

This question has been half-answered before:

- [Pascal / Delphi / Pascal Script tags](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1944/31503)

It was explicitly asked again here:

- [Should we have a [free-pascal] tag?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5141/should-we-have-a-free-pascal-tag)

but no answer was given.

Now [a bunch of suggested edits](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/62263/cpicanco?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) have put the tag in place on a few questions, and I think it's a better solution to create a synonym from [free-pascal](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/free-pascal) back to [pascal](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pascal) instead.

Neither tag is a high-volume tag, and there's currently only 1 [free-pascal](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/free-pascal) question (and a number of proposed ones).

Fragmenting the already small tag makes no sense on Code Review.

Can a mod please create the synonym?

Comment: I think we should get an expert opinion about the difference first. If they are similar enough, synonimize. Otherwise, they may co-exist like python2 and python3.

Comment: To make things clear: I'm against the massive influx of suggested re-tagging by a user which does not have the reputation to do it the proper way.

Comment: As far as I know, I was using my "create tag" privilege.

Comment: @cpicanco Can you please expand on that? Your current comment makes very little sense I'm afraid.

Comment: Well, I don't know how the check all my current privileges, but I remember I earned the "Create new tags" some time ago.

Comment: Please, note that "create new tag" is different from "edit tag wiki". I recently proposed an edit to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/free-pascal/info and it was approved. So I started fixing the errors I found. Please, reconsider you downvote.

Comment: For even more recent discussion: http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/6137/31562

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *fragmenting the already small tag makes no sense on Code Review*

I completely agree, and I've created the synonym.

Comment: I understand the fragmenting argument. Please, consider that [pascal] is sometimes used together with the Delphi tag, which will generate a conflict. Make me know if I should revise Delphi Tags to see if they were mistakenly tagged and propose changes accordingly.

Comment: Further, I think you are generating confusion to the [delphi], [delphi-xe] taggers, that with some chance will also use the [pascal] tag all together. Is not clear why [free-pascal] should be a synonym for [pascal] in this context.

Comment: @cpicanco this isn't about whether [tag:delphi] is [tag:pascal] or vice-versa. It's about a tag that has very little exposure and usage, and whether it's worth creating a separate tag for one or two questions. the answer is no, it's not worth it. we cross the bridge when we get to the river.

Comment: I wasn't talking about differences between delphi and pascal. I was talking about the behaviour of the people using a confusing tag system. You can't cross the bridge if it is broken.

Comment: Better, you can't get to the river if you are lost.